# keep only xml elements with unique attributes with XSLT 3.0

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, unique

Newbie here. I have a large XML file.
I would like to keep only the elements `<w>` which have and attribute `@lemma` with no duplicates (i.e. keep only elements with a unique `@lemma` value)

Sample:

```
<p>
    <w xml:lang="arn" lemma="one">a</w>
    <w xml:lang="arn" lemma="two">b</w>
    <w xml:lang="arn" lemma="three">c</w>
    <w xml:lang="arn" lemma="one">d</w>
    <w xml:lang="arn" lemma="two">e</w>
</p>
```

output should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>
    <w xml:lang="arn" lemma="three">c</w>
</p>
```

since it is the only `<w>` with the `@lemma="three"`

Many thanks!

Comment: Well, key or group the `w` elements on `@lemma` and keep only those for which `count(current-group())` or `count(key('key-name', @lemma))` is `1`. The grouping intro in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding Martin's answer,

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="w" group-by="@lemma">
  <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) = 1">
    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

You haven't said what you mean by "large" but if it's so large that you need to use streaming, then a solution using `xsl:iterate` would be possible. It can't be 100% streamed of course because you need to track what keys you have seen, but with a semi-streamed solution you can discard elements as soon as you know they are duplicates.